# puppet is not creating agent_catalog_run.lock file

Tags: ansible, locking, puppet

I have an ansible script that starts puppet agent and then waits for /var/lib/puppet/state/agent_catalog_run.lock file.

I found that this file is not getting created on target machine.
Ansible version is: 1.9.7 and puppet agent version is: 3.8.7
I checked on target linux machine and puppet agent is in running state.

Below is ansible script line:

```yaml
- name: ensure that puppet lock file is created
  wait_for:
    path: /var/lib/puppet/state/agent_catalog_run.lock
    timeout: 1800
```

What are things that should be checked in this scenario ?
(Note: No puppet logs have been created.)

Comment: Those are both ancient versions of Ansible and Puppet. You may have all kinds of issues related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is simply checking for the wrong file.

As the name suggests, the [agent_catalog_run.lock](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/configuration.html#agentcatalogrunlockfile) is:

> A lock file to indicate that a puppet agent catalog run is currently in progress. The file contains the pid of the process that holds the lock on the catalog run.

In other words, that file will only be there if a Puppet agent run is occurring.

You may want the [pidfile](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/configuration.html#pidfile) instead, which is:

> The file containing the PID of a running process. This file is intended to be used by service management frameworks and monitoring systems to determine if a puppet process is still in the process table.
>
> - Default: $rundir/${run_mode}.pid

(Where `$run_mode` would be "agent".)

Note that you can inspect your actual settings using puppet config print, e.g.:

```
▶ puppet config print pidfile
/Users/alexharvey/.puppetlabs/var/run/main.pid
```

Yours will be different because mine is running as the non root user on a Mac OS X laptop. Thus, I *think* you will need to change your code to:

```yaml
- name: wait for the puppet PID file to be created
  wait_for:
    path: /var/run/agent.pid
    timeout: 1800
```